# How can i fetch value from this xml

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

I have xml file from an external url http://www.xmlcharts.com/cache/precious-metals.xml

```
<prices>
<pricelist currency="usd">
<price timestamp="1356079920" per="ozt" commodity="gold">1649.45</price>
<price timestamp="1356079680" per="ozt" commodity="palladium">676.00</price>
<price timestamp="1356079740" per="ozt" commodity="platinum">1553.75</price>
<price timestamp="1356079860" per="ozt" commodity="silver">29.95</price>
</pricelist>
<pricelist currency="eur">
<price timestamp="1356079920" per="ozt" commodity="gold">1248.80</price>
<price timestamp="1356079680" per="ozt" commodity="palladium">511.80</price>
<price timestamp="1356079740" per="ozt" commodity="platinum">1176.34</price>
<price timestamp="1356079860" per="ozt" commodity="silver">22.68</price>
</pricelist>
<pricelist currency="chf">
<price timestamp="1356079920" per="ozt" commodity="gold">1507.76</price>
<price timestamp="1356079680" per="ozt" commodity="palladium">617.93</price>
<price timestamp="1356079740" per="ozt" commodity="platinum">1420.28</price>
<price timestamp="1356079860" per="ozt" commodity="silver">27.38</price>
</pricelist>
</prices>
```

I have used PHP for loading this via

```
$xmlobj = simplexml_load_file($feedurl);
print_r($xmlobj->pricelist);
```

which give output like:

```
SimpleXMLElement Object ( [pricelist] => Array ( [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [@attributes] => Array ( [currency] => usd ) [price] => Array ( [0] => 1649.45 [1] => 676.00 [2] => 1553.75 [3] => 29.95 ) ) [1] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [@attributes] => Array ( [currency] => eur ) [price] => Array ( [0] => 1248.80 [1] => 511.80 [2] => 1176.34 [3] => 22.68 ) ) [2] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [@attributes] => Array ( [currency] => chf ) [price] => Array ( [0] => 1507.76 [1] => 617.93 [2] => 1420.28 [3] => 27.38 ) ) ) )
```

I have tried `$xmlobj->pricelist` but cant get the **price** value...

Comment: @Jan Hančič any reason for voted down....

Comment: I didn't down voted you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file('http://www.xmlcharts.com/cache/precious-metals.xml');

foreach($xml as $pricelist) {
    // if($pricelist->attributes()->currency == 'usd')
    foreach($pricelist as $price) {
        echo $price[0].' ';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you really examine your output from `print_r($xmlobj->pricelist);` you can see that it *is* grabbing the prices of each item. Try accessing the prices by treating `pricelist` as an object. Access the prices via: `$xmlobj->pricelist->price[1]` and see if that works.

I say this because the `$xmlobj->pricelist->price` array contains the droids you are looking for.

Comment: Oops. Try `$xmlobj->pricelist->price` array instead.

Comment: $xmlobj->pricelist->prices Gives-> SimpleXMLElement Object ( )... ;(

Comment: Right, but I accidentally said "priceS" instead of "price". If you actually read the output you're getting from print_r(), you'll see quite clearly that the prices are in fact there inside that object, in an array called "price". Try `$xmlobj->pricelist->price` and see if that works.

Answer (score 0):

```
$load_xml = simplexml_load_file("http://www.xmlcharts.com/cache/precious-metals.xml"); 
echo $load_xml->pricelist[0]->price[0]; //is gold

echo $load_xml->pricelist[0]->price[1]; //is palladium
echo $load_xml->pricelist[0]->price[2]; //is platinum
echo $load_xml->pricelist[0]->price[3]; //is silver
```